# Can I upgrade batteries voltage from 60v 20Ah to 72v 20Ah by wiring 60v 20Ah and 12v 20Ah?

Tags: batteries

I have a 60v 20ah 21700 lithium battery on my e-bike. I want to upgrade 60v 20ah to 72v 20ah, so can I connect 60v 20Ah and 12v 20Ah to be 72v 20Ah?
Or how to upgrade that, please?

Comment: what is the 60 V battery made of? ... what is the 12 V battery made of?

Comment: Battery may have BMS which control each cell. If you change amount of cells and your BMS can not control more cells, you have a problem. Replacing with new BMS required.

Comment: Check whether (legal) limits to motor power apply where you want to ride. The smaller battery in such a setup has been called a booster pack in functional models. Is the controller specified to operate at 75 V? Does it limit phase("motor") current to reasonable values?

Comment: (They used to be wild over at [Endless Sphere](https://endless-sphere.com/forums/).)